# Problem integrating Service Workers into Symfony project

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to integrate Service workers in my Symfony project in order to cache some files and make my page into a PWA and make it work offline.

Sadly, I stumbled into a problem and I've been trying to fix it for a week now without any success.

My problem here is inside my Service Worker js file. I was actually able to call the service but could not find the pages inside it, which generated an error since it could not find the pages linked inside the js file.

Here's my code sw.js:

```
var cacheName = 'hello-pwa';
var filesToCache = [
'../manifest.json',
'../favicon.ico',
'../../../templates/User/User.html.twig'
];

/* Start the service worker and cache all of the app's content */
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

/* Serve cached content when offline */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

The manifest.json and favicon cache just fine but when I add '../../../templates/User/User.html.twig' I get the following error (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed).

Please help me guys I've been trying to solve this for a whole week.

Here's an image of my folder:https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTp2a.jpg

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - but the PWA files (HTML, images, css, etc) likely have to be  under the public directory - files under Symfony "templates" are not accessible to client scripts, browsers, etc.

Comment: Ah I think you're right, so do you think there's any solution for this. I can't just copy (or change) all my files under template to public and even if I did I won't be able to pass data from the controllers to those pages.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html

Comment: I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the web server, Symfony uses Twig to compile a twig template file down to plain PHP code.  PHP then converts the php file to a html file which is served to the client web browser.  The web browser reads html, css and js files, not twig or php files.
The `filesToCache` array in the question example should be renamed `urlsToCache`. 
 `urlsToCache` cannot contain the `User.html.twig` file but rather should contain a URL such as `../user`.

There are two options for generating the html file.  Pass data from the Symfony controller to a twig page and generate the user html file to cache statically.  Or have the twig template generate an outline for the look of the web page.  Update the web page dynamically in the browser.  When online, use Ajax calls to retrieve data from the server and cache in [localStorage](https://javascript.info/localstorage) or [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB).  When offline, retrieve data from the cache to update the web page.

Not every application can be converted to a Progressive Web Application that can work offline.  The application needs to use a relatively small database that fits in browser cache and is not updated too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the cache filenames you wrote, I regret to inform you that when you loaded your Service Worker, it was not located in the root of the scope. You cannot cache files with `../` – you can fix this by placing the Service Worker in the root of the project, changing your cache to reflect `/filename.ext`, and that should do the trick.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed

Always, without exception, points to a misspelled (in cache function of your service worker) or missing file (on the host) in your cache, and can be caused by your service worker being in a subdirectory, not the root of the project.